# How to create spec from data

Tags: clojure, specifications

I am trying to create spec just from data. I have very complex data structure - all nested map.

```
{:contexts
 ({:importer.datamodel/global-id "01b4e69f86e5dd1d816e91da27edc08e",
   :importer.datamodel/type "province",
   :name "a1",
   :importer.datamodel/part-of "8cda1baed04b668a167d4ca28e3cef36"}
  {:importer.datamodel/global-id "8cda1baed04b668a167d4ca28e3cef36",
   :importer.datamodel/type "country",
   :name "AAA"}
  {:importer.datamodel/global-id "c78e5478e19f2d7c1b02088e53e8d8a4",
   :importer.datamodel/type "location",
   :importer.datamodel/center ["36." "2."],
   :importer.datamodel/part-of "01b4e69f86e5dd1d816e91da27edc08e"}
  {:importer.datamodel/global-id "88844f94f79c75acfcb957bb41386149",
   :importer.datamodel/type "organisation",
   :name "C"}
  {:importer.datamodel/global-id "102e96468e5d13058ab85c734aa4a949",
   :importer.datamodel/type "organisation",
   :name "A"}),
 :datasources
 ({:importer.datamodel/global-id "Source;ACLED",
   :name "ACLED",
   :url "https://www.acleddata.com"}),
 :iois
 ({:importer.datamodel/global-id "item-set;ACLED",
   :importer.datamodel/type "event",
   :datasource "Source;ACLED",
   :features
   ({:importer.datamodel/global-id
     "c74257292f584502f9be02c98829d9fda532a492e7dd41e06c31bbccc76a7ba0",
     :date "1997-01-04",
     :fulltext
     {:importer.datamodel/global-id "df5c7d6d075df3a7719ebdd39c6d4c7f",
      :text "bla"},
     :location-meanings
     ({:importer.datamodel/global-id
       "e5611219971164a15f06e07228fb7b51",
       :location "8cda1baed04b668a167d4ca28e3cef36",
       :contexts (),
       :importer.datamodel/type "position"}
      {:importer.datamodel/global-id
       "af36461d27ec1d8d28fd7f4a70ab7ce2",
       :location "c78e5478e19f2d7c1b02088e53e8d8a4",
       :contexts (),
       :importer.datamodel/type "position"}),
     :interaction-name "Violence",
     :importer.datamodel/type "description",
     :has-contexts
     ({:context "102e96468e5d13058ab85c734aa4a949",
       :context-association-type "actor",
       :context-association-name "actor-1",
       :priority "none"}
      {:context "88844f94f79c75acfcb957bb41386149",
       :context-association-type "actor",
       :context-association-name "actor-2",
       :priority "none"}),
     :facts
     ({:importer.datamodel/global-id
       "c46802ce6dcf33ca02ce113ffd9a855e",
       :importer.datamodel/type "integer",
       :name "fatalities",
       :value "16"}),
     :attributes
     ({:name "description",
       :importer.datamodel/type "string",
       :value "Violence"})}),
   :attributes (),
   :ioi-slice "per-item"})}
```

What tool can create the spec for such a structure?
I am trying to use this tool: https://github.com/stathissideris/spec-provider

but it gives me this:

```
(spec/def :importer.datamodel/data
  (clojure.spec.alpha/coll-of
   (clojure.spec.alpha/or
    :collection
    (clojure.spec.alpha/coll-of
     (clojure.spec.alpha/keys
      :req
      [:importer.datamodel/global-id]
      :opt
      [:importer.datamodel/center
       :importer.datamodel/part-of
       :importer.datamodel/type]
      :opt-un
      [:importer.datamodel/attributes
       :importer.datamodel/datasource
       :importer.datamodel/features
       :importer.datamodel/ioi-slice
       :importer.datamodel/name
       :importer.datamodel/url]))
    :simple
    clojure.core/keyword?)))
```

which is not complete solution...
I use `(sp/pprint-specs (sp/infer-specs data :importer.datamodel/data) 'data 's)`...
What tool can create the spec for such a structure?

Comment: Do not ask the same question multiple times; this is considered "noise" on Stack Overflow. I have refunded your bounty here, marked the question as a duplicate of your other one (which also has a bounty), and merged them so that the answer is not lost (and remains eligible for the bounty).